# SSIS 2008 Lookup - Getting Started

Tags: ssis

Using SSIS 2008 R2, I have an OLE DB source with around 30 fields.  Ultimately my destination is an Excel spreadsheet however I have a number of transformations along the way, including Lookups, Derived Columns, Data Transformations and Script components.

At the moment I am stuck on Lookups.

In my source data I have 6 columns where the value needs to be replaced with a value from a lookup table.  There are 6 different lookup tables, each with it's own key.  (The lookup tables are not related to each other).

My understanding is that I need to include 6 lookup transformations in the data flow however I am having difficulty getting started.

In the lookup transformation editor:

- General: Left the defaults
- Connection: Specified my OLE DB connection manager, and my (2-column) lookup table
- Columns: Here's where I get stuck.  I have availabe inputs, and available lookup columns, but no way to show the relationship between them.  What am I supposed to configure here?  I can specific a lookup column, a lookup operation, and an output alias.  But how do I relate the input to the reference table???

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match up the Lookup columns:  Click on the field in the table on the left (Available Input Columns), then drag your mouse pointer to the matching field in the other table (Available Lookup Columns).  This defines what fields to match.

Then, to specify what column to return (ie. output), click on the checkbox next to that column in the table on the right.

Comment: Thanks Joe!  That's sorted it.